# Post Image to the Facebook using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I got the code from the Facebook page to publish the Photo to the user's wall (account).

Below is my **PostToFB.php** file:

```
<?php
    include_once "facebook.php";
    ini_set("display_errors",0);

    //configuring application to post.
    $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
    $post_login_url = "YOUR_REDIRECT_URL";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission
    if(empty($code)){
        $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
                . "client_id=" .  $app_id
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                .  "&scope=publish_stream";
        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
                . "'</script>");
    }
    else {
        $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                . "client_id=" . $app_id
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
                . "&code=" . $code;
        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $access_token = $params['access_token'];

        // Show photo upload form to user and post to the Graph URL
        $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
                . "access_token=" .$access_token;

        echo '<html><body>';
        echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
                .$graph_url .' "method="POST">';
        echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
        echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</body></html>';
    }
?>
```

But this is not working. I get below Output:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

Can you please help me to solve this?

Thank You,

Comment: This works fine for me. Are you using this with the admin's account?

Comment: Yes using the account in which I have created the app.

Comment: @SahilMittal do you have any solution for my problem?
I am not able to locate the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works absolutely fine. Only probably reason seems to me is that you have not granted the permission for the photo upload. Check which permissions you have granted to your app from here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

[image]

If still didnt helped, you can create  a new app and try again; since this code is correct.

**Edit:**

`publish_stream` is deprecated, try using `publish_actions`

Comment: Hi @sahilMittal Yes you are right...
In my setting tab only "Your Public Profile" and "Your Photos" is didplaying...
But I am asking for user permission (publich_stream) in the code...
And that permission is not showing in the status&review tab under the "Add Items to This Submission" button...
Is there anything you can help me out?

Comment: I have also tried to create a new app and run the code...
But still I get failure...

Comment: When you created the new app and then granted the permission, did you saw the screenshot that I have pasted

Comment: No... it is not showing this kind of message...
But that is the problem... How can I give that permission in the app UI?
I have given that permission in the code... Line 18.

Comment: That's seem to be impossible, since the permission is present i nthe login url. Try `publish_actions` instead of `publish_stream` and let me know

Comment: That's great. Thumbs up!

Comment: one another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625875/post-image-to-the-facebook-using-graph-api-by-giving-the-source-of-the-file

Comment: there is another question related to this.
Please see below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731360/post-image-to-the-facebook-using-graph-api-allows-limited-photos

Comment: Hi
Can you please help me to solve below problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762287/facebook-graph-api-logout-url-is-not-working
I have posted it before many time. But still got no response.

Comment: Hello
I am facing a problem while importing photos from user timeline.
If user have uploaded multiple images, then those images are not being imported in my website. Otherwise all is working as expected.