# Post Image to the Facebook using Graph API by Giving the source of the file

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can upload the image to the facebook acoount using below code:

```
<?php
    include_once "facebook.php";
    ini_set("display_errors",0);

    //configuring application to post.
    $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
    $post_login_url = "YOUR_REDIRECT_URL";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission
    if(empty($code)){
        $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
                . "client_id=" .  $app_id
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                .  "&scope=publish_actions";
        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
                . "'</script>");
    }
    else {
        $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                . "client_id=" . $app_id
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
                . "&code=" . $code;
        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $access_token = $params['access_token'];

        // Show photo upload form to user and post to the Graph URL
        $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
                . "access_token=" .$access_token;

        echo '<html><body>';
        echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
                .$graph_url .' "method="POST">';
        echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
        echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</body></html>';
    }
?>
```

But as you can see, I am using form tag and submit button to post an image using the input type as File.
But I don't want to browse for the image.
I want to remove all the code for browsing and just want to give the source of the image to upload that image to facebook account.

Something Like below:

```
<?php
    include_once "facebook.php";
    ini_set("display_errors",0);

    //configuring application to post.
    $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
    $post_login_url = "YOUR_REDIRECT_URL";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission

    if(empty($code)){
        $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
                . "client_id=" .  $app_id
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                .  "&scope=publish_actions";
        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
                . "'</script>");
    }
    else {
        $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                . "client_id=" . $app_id
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
                . "&code=" . $code;
        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        //echo "Response: $response<br>";
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $access_token = $params['access_token'];
    //  echo "Access Token: $access_token<br>"; 

        // Show photo upload form to user and post to the Graph URL
        $graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=" .$access_token;

        echo '<html><body>';
        echo '<form action="'.$graph_url .'"method="POST">';
        //echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>'; Putting img tag instead of file
        echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/download.php?f='.apply_filters('filter_if_add_to_cart',$image_link).'"><br/><br/>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</body></html>';
    }
?>
```

But I don't know how to do that.
Can you please help me with this?
Thank You,

**Update:** I have updated my code. Please see below for the updated Code:

```
<?php
    include_once "facebook.php";
    ini_set("display_errors",0);

    $img_src = $_SESSION['imgSrc'];

    //configuring application to post.
    $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
    $post_login_url = "YOUR_REDIRECT_URL";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission
    if(empty($code)){
        $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
                . "client_id=" .  $app_id
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                .  "&scope=publish_actions";
        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
                . "'</script>");
    }
    else {
        $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                . "client_id=" . $app_id
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
                . "&code=" . $code;
        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        //echo "Response: $response<br>";
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $access_token = $params['access_token'];

        //Posting Image to The Facebook

        $api_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/photos';
        $attachment =  array(
                'url'  => "{$img_src}",
                'access_token' => $access_token
        );
        $api_response = UseCurl($api_url, $attachment);
        $post_result = json_decode($api_response, TRUE);
        print_r($post_result);

        function UseCurl($url, $attachment){
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);

            return $result;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: That means you have the images in the server right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have images in the server that you wish to post, you can simply use the `url` parameter to upload the photo. Just like this-

```
$api_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/photos';
$attachment =  array(
   'url'  => "{image-url}",
   'access_token' => $access_token
);
$api_response = UseCurl($api_url, $attachment);
$post_result = json_decode($api_response, TRUE);
print_r($post_result);

function UseCurl($url, $attachment){
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close ($ch);

   return $result;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code...
Please see it in the question under "Update:"
It is right?

Comment: Yes...

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function UseCurl() in /var/www/picpixa2/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-facebook/postToFB.php on line 42 Call Stack: 0.0006 349492 1. {main}() /var/www/picpixa2/wp-content/plugins/create-own-object/plugin-facebook/postToFB.php:0 "

Comment: You are writing the function inside the `if` statement? Its a very basic error in PHP, I didnt expected this error from you

Comment: This error came:
Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => An unknown error has occurred. [type] => OAuthException [code] => 1 ) )

Comment: You sure you have replaced `{image-url}` with your correct image url? If yes, can you share the image url?

Comment: Here is the url I am sending: https://www.picpixa.com/wp-content/themes/picpixa/download.php?f=https://www.picpixa.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/CA-VelcroCanCooler-Upload-14.jpgArray

Comment: Is this the valid image url? I'm getting this - `Warning: opendir(/home/picpixa/.pki): failed to open dir: Permission denied in /home/picpixa/wp-content/themes/picpixa/download.php on line 109 Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource.....`. Please give the correct image url and this ill work

Comment: It is valid url and working...
Thanks for the code...
It's working perfectly...
Thank you so much...

Comment: Hi @sahilMittal
I don't know there is some error occuring while posting an Image.
I have not change the code...
It was working before and now it is not working....
I am talking about the code you have provided in the answer...
Error is as below:
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [message] => An unknown error has occurred.
            [type] => OAuthException
            [code] => 1
        )

)

Comment: Its probably an OAuth issue. Try logging out and then login again with  a fresh access token and then try

Comment: Hello I am facing a problem while importing photos from user timeline.
If user have uploaded multiple images, then those images are not being imported in my website. Otherwise all is working as expected.