# Post Image to the Facebook using Graph API (Allows Limited Photos) and add some more features

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using below code to post the image to user's wall.

postToFB.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ini_set("display_errors",1);
    include_once "facebook.php";

    //The value of $img_src was getting null because the page reloads after the authorization.
    //So I stored the value of the image source in the session.
    //And then stored that value in $img_src
    //By Ashish Shah

    if($_GET["f"]){
        $_SESSION['imgSrc'] = $_GET["f"];
    }

    $img_src = $_SESSION['imgSrc'];

    $app_id = "APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
    $post_login_url = "REDIRECT_URL";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];
    $location = $_SESSION['backUrl'];
    //echo "Image URL: ".$img_src;
    //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission
    if(empty($code)){
        $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
                . "client_id=" .  $app_id
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                .  "&scope=publish_actions";
        echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
                . "'</script>");
    }
    else {
        $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                . "client_id=" . $app_id
                . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
                . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
                . "&code=" . $code;
        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        //echo "Response: $response<br>";
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $access_token = $params['access_token'];

        //Posting Image to The Facebook

        $api_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/photos';
        $attachment =  array(
                'url'  => "{$img_src}",
                'access_token' => $access_token
        );
        $api_response = UseCurl($api_url, $attachment);
        $post_result = json_decode($api_response, TRUE);
        header('Refresh: 5; URL='.$location);
        #print_r($post_result);
        echo "You have uploaded the image to your facebook account.<br>";
        echo "Now you will be redirected to the previous page.";
    }
    function UseCurl($url, $attachment){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

        return $result;
    }
?>
```

And this is working perfectly.
But my problem is there is some limit to uploading.

This code is making an album of my app's name and stores all the uploaded (Posted) images in that album.
Now, I have to delete the images of that album to upload more after some number of images I have uploading. I don't know the exact number of images allowed.
Can any one help me with this so that user have not to delete the images to upload (post) more images using my app?

Thank you,

**Update:**

With the above question I also want to add some features such as while uploading I want to make user select the sharing options like "Share With Friends" such as in the facebook itself.
Is there any way to add this feature using my original code?

Comment: I think its 100 images/album

Comment: so is there any way to increase this limit or make it unlimited?

Comment: @sahilMittal can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: Hello,
I am facing a problem while importing photos from user timeline.
If user have uploaded multiple images, then those images are not being imported in my website. Otherwise all is working as expected.